# Lerna and webpack aliases issue

Tags: webpack, lerna

Imagine two projects (ex. my-app and my-ui) using webpack aliases to resolve 'components' as './src/components'. I use Lerna to locally "link" this projects and simplify development, my-ui is a dependency of my-app (set in it's package.json) and imported like :

**MyApp**

/src/main.js :

```
import UI from 'my-ui';
```

**MyUI**

/src/main.js

```
import Button from 'components/button';
export default Button;
```

/src/components/button/main.js

```
export default class Button...
```

When MyApp start, MyUI try to resolve Button in "*MyApp/src/components/*" instead of "*MyApp/node_modules/my-ui/src/components*" or "*MyApp/node_modules/my-ui/lib/app.js*". I dont find how to resolve this issue !

The resolve section from my Webpack config :

```
resolve: {
  mainFiles: ['index', 'main'],
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  alias: {
    lib: helpers.getPath('src/lib/'),
    components: helpers.getPath('src/components/'),
  },
  modules: [
    helpers.getPath('src'),
    helpers.getPath('node_modules'),
  ],
},
```

Where the getPath method is :

```
const path = require('path');
const projectPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');
const getPath = path.join.bind(path, projectPath);
```

Comment: can you show your webpack.config.js

Comment: I have updated my question with a litte part (resolve section) of my webpack config. Do you want another part ? NOTE: each project has this webpack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

add webpack loader to Change MyUI alias path.

```
module.exports = function(content) {
  let prefix = "MyUI/";
  if (this.context.includes("/src") && this.context.includes(prefix)) {
    let relativePath = this.context
      .slice(this.context.indexOf(prefix))
      .replace(prefix, "");
    let pkgName = `${prefix}${relativePath.slice(
      0,
      relativePath.indexOf("/")
    )}`;
    content = content.replace(/@\//g, `${pkgName}/src/`);
  }
  return content;
};
```